# Is there any way to unjs (like uncss)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

If we are using `Bootstrap` or other front end frameworks(not quite sure), we can [customize](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) it by deselecting unused selector and then download it.

When it comes to javascript, like `jquery` for instance, minified version of 1.10.2 is 90.92kb([source](http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/jquery-size/)). If I only use one or two effect, is there any way to **unjs** it, just like the CSS way [uncss](https://github.com/addyosmani/grunt-uncss).

Comment: You can build your own jQuery build as described in the GitHub repos https://github.com/jquery/jquery#modules. There is no (at least I don't think there is) a web interface for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use Google's  [Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/)  It "parses your JavaScript, analyzes it, removes dead code and rewrites and minimizes what's left. It also checks syntax, variable references, and types, and warns about common JavaScript pitfalls."

There's also Bransey's [Dead JS Eliminator](https://github.com/bramsey/Dead-Javascript-Eliminator) available on Github

Comment: I see both those tools analyse javascript files in themselves and not in relation to any html where they might be triggered. Any idea if those tools can somehow be made to analyse what js is triggered in the actual html context? uncss for example required paths to html files in order to see what gets used and what not.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet but maybe it would be possible to simulate event triggering with a test file? Example, if a source file has `$el.on('click', doSomething);` then the test file could do `$el.click();` or `doSomething(new Event(...)).bind(this)`;